# How to add a Contact in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I've got the following data class:

```
data class Contact(
        val id : String,
        val name : String,
        val number : String)
```

I now want to add a Contact to the Contact list of the phone using a method inside a BoundService.
I've got the following code right now:

```
fun importContact(Contact: Contact) {
        val intent = Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION)
        intent.type = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, Contact.name)
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, Contact.number)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

However as this method is run inside a BoundService it throws me the following Exception:
`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error says it all .. Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to Intent .

Comment: @ADM Could you maybe explain on why this error occurs without the Flag? So what's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#fant-required

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as adding this to it:

```
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Somehow I didn't even try the suggested solution in the error.

So whole code needs to look like this:

```
fun importContact(Contact: Contact) {
        val intent = Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION)
        intent.type = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, Contact.name)
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, Contact.number)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: is this really useful then ? i mean, you had code which gave you an explicit suggestion on how to fix it, which you then applied and now it's working...